# parallax scrolling down with ActionScript 3.0

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

> i want create road parallax scrolling down with flash in as3, when i run the script, the parallax moving up. and this my code

```
package {
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.events.Event;

public class kelas extends MovieClip{
```

> this i create variable

```
    public var road:road1;
    public var road2:road1;
    public var roadContainer:MovieClip;
    public var roadBreadth:Number;
    public var car:Car;

    public function kelas(){
```

> and this create car , road and container

```
        car = new Car();
        road = new road1();
        road2 = new road1();
        roadBreadth = 653.7;

        car.y = 10.0;
        car.x = 10;
        road.y = 10.0;
        road.x = 10;
        road2.y = road.y + roadBreadth;
        road2.x = road.x;

        //* add child object
        roadContainer = new MovieClip();
        roadContainer.addChild(road);
        roadContainer.addChild(road2);
        this.addChild(roadContainer);

        this.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, onEnterFrame);

public function onEnterFrame(event:Event):void
    {

        car.y = car.y + 15;
        roadContainer.y = 10 - car.y + 10;

        if (road.y + roadBreadth + roadContainer.y < 0)
        {
            road.y = road.y + (2 * roadBreadth);
        }
        if (road2.y + roadBreadth + roadContainer.y < 0)
        {
            road2.y = road2.y + (2 * roadBreadth);
        }
    }
}
```

> i want this backgroung moving down is not moving up, please help me

Comment: This line.. `if (road.y + roadBreadth + roadContainer.y < 0)` is most likely not doing what you think it is. Here it says `if (10.0 + 653.7 + (-5) is smaller than ZERO) { then make road.y = 10 + (1307.4) }`. What are you trying to achieve here exactly?? What object in your code is the background exactly? Is it road? or roadContainer?

Comment: Read **[this link](http://www.republicofcode.com/tutorials/flash/as3conditionals/)** scroll down to "Logical Operators" section to understand how to check _thing-A AND thing-B_ using `&&` or also _thing-A OR thing-B_ using `||`

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this sample, it's a pretty simple idea to wrap an object around. Make sure your multiplier is set to the amount of roads that you're wrapping.

```
if (road.y > 600) {
    road.y -= road.y * 2;
} else {
    road.y++;
}
```

Comment: No, you'll have to implement my general idea into your code, after all you're more familiar with it. :p

Comment: hahaha. can you edit my code for the background moving down :D

Answer (score 0):

may be your `roadContainer` contains road, so when you  move `roadContainer`, you moves road too.
so, just move don't let it contains, add when you move the background.y++, road will like moving up